# Pygame event object

Tags: python, pygame

Is it possible to define an event object in pygame?

What I am trying to do is loop through all the keyboard events in a method, I then want to call that method with an event as a parameter, but I first need to define it. Is this possible?

Im using Pygame 3.3 and python 3.

Comment: Did you already check http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html ?

Answer (score 1):

An event can be made with the command `pygame.event.Event(type, dict)`.  The type will be what you want it to return when the `event.type()` command is used on it.  The dict will include every other attribute.

An example: `pygame.event.Event(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, {'button':1})` would return a `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event with an attribute `button` of 1.